# Count the number of times a method is called in Java

Tags: java

I want to count how many times a method is called over the last 30 minutes.

Currently I'm using **redis** to record every call with a *ttl* and thus increment on each call. However, I want to be able to do this fully in Java without using an external tool.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: You could increment a counter which you log every 1 to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

My prefer way is to using interceptor. If you are using JEE or Spring you can directly use their interceptors. However you can also implement your own (on-demand) interceptor or use AspectJ.